# how to get spinners selected data from dynamically added layout?

Tags: android

I have 3 spinner which are dependent to each other.on clicking first spinner second spinner will be shown and on clicking second spinner 3rd spinner will be shown  and they are inside one layout.at the bottom of layout there are 2 button .one for to add layout  and other one to get all the spinners data.suppose if i  click add button 3 times mean 3 layout will be added each having 3 dependent spinners.each  different layout have close button also if user click on  that button then that particular layout will be remove...how can i achieve this  in android...

i have made made database in sqlite and fetch data also but couldnot get proper data from dynamic added layout spinners..

> java

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class AddMorePage extends AppCompatActivity {
    int addMoreCounter = 0;
    LinearLayout linearLayout1;
    ArrayList<String> modList;
    ArrayList<String> subModList;
    ArrayList<String> questionList;
    ArrayList<String> moduleIdList;
    Spinner spinner;
    Spinner spinners;
    ArrayList<Spinner> modSpinnerList;
    ArrayList<Spinner> subModSpinnerList;
    ArrayList<Spinner> qnSpinnerList;
      ArrayList<String> moduleNameList;
      UserDb userDb;
      SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
      ArrayList<HashMap> moduleMap;
      ArrayList<HashMap> subModuleByIdMap;
      ArrayList<String> subModuleByIDNameList;
      ArrayList<String> subModuleByIdIdList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> smoduleAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_more_page);
        userDb = new UserDb(getApplicationContext());
        sqLiteDatabase = userDb.getReadableDatabase();

        modList = new ArrayList<>();
        subModList = new ArrayList<>();
        questionList = new ArrayList<>();
        linearLayout1 = findViewById(R.id.normalLayout);

        //for spinner list
        modSpinnerList = new ArrayList< >();
        subModSpinnerList = new ArrayList< >();
        qnSpinnerList = new ArrayList< >();

        //for data arraylist
        moduleNameList = new ArrayList< >();
        moduleIdList = new ArrayList< >();
        subModuleByIDNameList = new ArrayList< >();
        subModuleByIdIdList = new ArrayList< >();


        moduleMap = userDb.getModuleData(sqLiteDatabase);
        for (HashMap<String, String> moduleM : moduleMap) {
            String moduleName = moduleM.get(UserDetail.Module.MODULE_NAME);
            String moduleId = moduleM.get(UserDetail.Module.MODULE_ID);
            moduleNameList.add(moduleName);
            moduleIdList.add(moduleId);
            Log.d("MODULENAME", moduleName);
            Log.d("MODULEID", moduleId);
        }
    }

    public void add(View view) {


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params =
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        70, 70);
        params.setMargins(0, 30, 30, 0);
        params.gravity = Gravity.END;

        modList.clear();
        subModList.clear();
        questionList.clear();
        addMoreCounter++;
        Log.d("countervalue", String.valueOf(addMoreCounter));

        modList.add("sanjeev1");
        modList.add("sanjeev2");
        modList.add("sanjeev3");
        modList.add("sanjeev4");

        subModList.add("sanjeevsub1");
        subModList.add("sanjeevsub2");
        subModList.add("sanjeevsub3");
        subModList.add("sanjeevsub4");

        questionList.add("sanjeevqn");
        questionList.add("sanjeevqn");
        questionList.add("sanjeevqn");
        questionList.add("sanjeevqn");

        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(AddMorePage.this);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        // creating LayoutParams
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsMain =
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        Button btnAddARoom = new Button(AddMorePage.this);
        //btnAddARoom.setText("Close");
        //btnAddARoom.setBackground(R.drawable.ic_lock);
        btnAddARoom.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_highlight_off);

        btnAddARoom.setLayoutParams(params);
        spinner = new Spinner(AddMorePage.this);
        spinners = new Spinner(AddMorePage.this);
        Spinner spinnerq = new Spinner(AddMorePage.this);



        // spinner adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> moduleAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, moduleNameList);

//        ArrayAdapter<String> smoduleAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
//                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, subModList);
        ArrayAdapter<String> qAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, questionList);

        spinner.setAdapter(moduleAdapter);
        //spinners.setAdapter(smoduleAdapter);
        spinnerq.setAdapter(qAdapter);

        linearLayout.addView(btnAddARoom);
        linearLayout.addView(spinner);
        linearLayout.addView(spinners);
        linearLayout.addView(spinnerq);
        linearLayout.addView(v);
        linearLayout1.addView(linearLayout);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String text = moduleNameList.get(i);
                Log.d("SPINNERDATA", text);

               // Log.d("SPINNERSIZE", String.valueOf(modSpinnerList.get(i)));

                 subModuleByIDNameList.clear();
                subModuleByIdIdList.clear();
                // Your code goes gere
                String staticSelectedModuleName = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                String staticSelectedModuleId = moduleIdList.get(i);
                Constant.GLOBAL_MODULE_ID = staticSelectedModuleId;
                Log.d("SELECTDMODULE",staticSelectedModuleName);
                Log.d("SELECTEDMODULEID",staticSelectedModuleName);
                 subModuleByIdMap = userDb.getSubModuleByIdData(staticSelectedModuleId ,sqLiteDatabase);
                for (HashMap<String, String> subModIDM : subModuleByIdMap) {
                    String subModNameById = subModIDM.get(UserDetail.SubModule.SUBMODULE_NAME);
                    String subModIdById = subModIDM.get(UserDetail.SubModule.SUBMODULE_ID);
                    subModuleByIDNameList.add(subModNameById);
                    subModuleByIdIdList.add(subModIdById);
                    Log.d("SUBMODULENAMEBYID", subModNameById);
                    Log.d("SUBMODULEIDBYID", subModIdById);
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show what you have tried yet ?

Comment: @sushildlh i have edited my qn and put all my code...would u please  help me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve dynamic layout, you can have a look on recycler view. Which you are able to create multiple layout item and access them individually in recycler view adapter class.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Comment: ::thank u..but i want to  put item  by  clicking above add button and how can i get it using recyler view

Comment: you can pass in a int as recycler view row count number, by default is 1. your add button listener will increase the number when use click on 1 and call recycler view adapter notifydatachanged function.

Comment: actually i have 1 layout  in beginning but when i  click add button  layout will be added ...i have 3 dependent spinners also...when i have more than 1 layout then these spinner  also donot work properly..how can i recognize spinners in different layout so that i can get all spinners  data properly after clicking get button

Comment: You need to change the id of each spinner in each layout, and add each listener. So i will recommend use recycler view where you can handle those listener in adapter class without need to manually change the id of each spinner.

Comment: i will try and let u know ok

Comment: i couldnot solve bro according to yangs solution..anybody has idea regarding it please help me..

Comment: @ sushildlh:::could u please help me?